# Django i18n: How to translate css content?

Tags: css, django, internationalization

Have the following css section:

> .introduction:before {
>      content: 'Who is going to translate me in a graceful way?';
>   }

Probably there is no easy way to handle i18n for css file, two possible choices:

1. gather all these css which with content and ship them together within Django templates.
2. generate i18n sensitive css name in template to choose different pre-translated css content.

Any **new possible solutions** will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have translations for each language in a different file, and load based on the language set in the session

Comment: @karthikr  Nice, if css content is too much, worth changing solution 2 to your solution.

Answer (score 4):

I would serve the css file that needs translating through Django and cache it per language to mitigate the performance hit.

urls.py

```
url(r'^static/css/translated.css$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='translated.css')),
```

translated.css

```
{% load cache %}
{% cache 60*60*24 translated_css LANGUAGE_CODE %}
  {# write css here, translate as a normal template #}
  .introduction:before { content: 
    {% trans 'Who is going to translate me in a graceful way?' %}
  ; }
{% endcache %}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is better than mixing css directly in templates.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is impossible. Only you can translate it if the css is a template (like the html template). But this is a bad solution.... efficiency

But if you have a class language in the body for example, you can have something like this:

```
body.language_en .introduction:before { content: 'Who is going to translate me in a graceful way?'; }
body.language_es .introduction:before { content: 'El traductor de google es terrible :-)'; }
```

And in your base.html something like this:

```
....
<body class="language_{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
....
```

Comment: Thanks Goin, these are the only two ways I could think of but none of them is good enough. The second way introduces new files to be translated or edited other than .po files.

Comment: Oh, maybe my question is not clear enough? I was more asking for new solutions than detailed explanation for those two solutions. But thank you anyway, and I agree with the Spanish content you wrote.

Comment: For once I can say something in Spanish that I wanted something that was really :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, for people that want to avoid serving the CSS files differently or duplicating CSS lines or files, would be to make use of [django javascript translation support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code).

Leave the original CSS in place as a backup. Then override the content using javascript by appending the translated style to the head of the page:

```
var trans_str = gettext("some content");
$('<style>.classWithContent:before{content:"' + trans_str + '" !important}' +
  '</style>').appendTo('head');
```

This is the version using JQuery but you can rewrite it in pure javascript easily. Add as many translated strings and override as many styles as you want.

This way you make use of [django internationalization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code) which you probably already have in place and translate CSS strings with minimal code. This solutions is obviously not applicable for heavy use of CSS content.